# Packaging with Pyinstaller - PyQt5 setStyle ignored

Tags: pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm actually have an similar issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111522/packaging-with-pyinstaller-pyqt4-qtgui-setstyle-ignored/48613000#48613000) after update python, pyistaller, pyqt5, pyqt5-tools. Before I got the desired **"Windows Vista-style"** without `app.setStyle('windowsvista')` when I run the compiled stand-alone executable.

Now I got the Windows **"Classic-style"** instead. If I start the application in PyCharm it will use the desired **"Windows Vista-style"**.

Currently installed on Win7 64bit:

Python     : 3.6.4

PyInstaller: 3.3.1

PyQt5      : 5.10

pyqt5-tools: 5.9.0.1.2 (*update to 5.9.1.1 doesn't work*)

Does anyone have any idea why PyInstaller ignored the style?

Comment: I have similar problem. No solution so far...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error seems to have been fixed in a unmerged branch of PyInstaller. More information can be found on [the GitHub pull request conversation](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/3233#issuecomment-362094587), but reinstalling PyInstaller using `pip install https://github.com/bjones1/pyinstaller/archive/pyqt5_fix.zip` fixed the same style issue for me on Mac.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times. The fix works on macOS as well as under Windows. Perfect

Comment: Glad this helped! If this answer works for you, could you mark it as accepted to show other viewers that there's a solution? Thanks!

Comment: For those who are looking for an answer and find that the link is broken, the fix is already merged upstream, but a new version wasn't released yet. Use this for now: `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip`.

Comment: For anyone who still have issues despite updated pyinstaller: I have managed to fix the ugly interface by carying over dll files from Qt plugin directory by the following pyinstaller switches: `--add-binary="%CONDA_PREFIX%\Library\plugins\styles;styles" --add-binary="%CONDA_PREFIX%\Library\plugins\platformthemes;platformthemes" --add-binary="%CONDA_PREFIX%\Library\plugins\platforms;platforms"`. I believe they are not carried over by default, because they are plugins (="optional"?).
Environment: conda 4.7.12, python 3.7.4, Pyinstaller 3.5, Pyside2 5.13.1